# Equation of a Circle Based on a Point and a Smaller Circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Creating the equation for a circle that revolves around another circle is fine (ignore the blue point):

[Circle with one point tangent to a smaller circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LP6o.png)

What I want to figure out is how to not only create a circle that is tangent to the smaller one, but one that also passes through the blue second point. The value of the point doesn't matter. How would I go about this?

Comment: Maybe useful , though the goal is not yet achieved : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ugdh1lftyr

Comment: 1. Are you looking for the equation of a circle that meets the conditions?

Comment: 2. Is there just one such circle or many?

Comment: are you looking for a reasonably simple way to find the coordinates of the centre of the circle? Then you could write down the equation of the circle...

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is the blue point and $Q$ is the tangency point on the big circle and the equation of the solution circle is $x^2+y^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0,$ then the two first equations are from $P,Q$ on the circle and the last from being tangent to the big circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$ by derivation of the two equations. $2x(Q)+2y(Q)y'(Q)=0$ and $2x(Q)+2y(Q)y'(Q)+2D+2Ey'(Q)=0,$

$\begin{align}
x(P)^2+y(P)^2+2D x(P)+2E y(P)+F&=0\\
x(Q)^2+y(Q)^2+2D x(Q)+2E y(Q)+F&=0\\
2D y(Q)-2E x(Q)&=0
\end{align}$

These determine $D,E,F$ and hence the equation of the solution circle.

[image: tgc]